# Mutable Borrows Inconsistency

Tags: rust, types, mutable, borrow-checker

The following program_pass compiles in Rust.

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 0;
    let mut y = &mut x;
    let mut z = &mut y;
    let mut last = &mut z;

    let mut alt_y = &mut x;
    let mut alt_z = &mut alt_y;

    z = &mut alt_y;  // *last = &mut alt_y;

}
```

The following program_error does not.

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 0;
    let mut y = &mut x;
    let mut z = &mut y;
    let mut last = &mut z;

    let mut alt_y = &mut x;
    let mut alt_z = &mut alt_y;

    *last = &mut alt_y;   // z = &mut alt_y;

}
```

What is violated in program_error, while not in program_pass?
Just started, but this is really going against what I thought to be my understanding of Rust.

Comment: I suppose it's something about mutating through a reference that rust cannot accept.

Comment: The compiler specifically points out `y` and `alt_y` as being mutable borrows of `x` before attempting to use one of them (`y`, via `last` and `z`). None of the borrows are used in the first code; you just make `z` borrow something else instead.

Comment: Instead of comparing two programs and asking "why does this one compile while the other one does not?" you should read the specific error details from the one that fails in order to understand *why* it is failing. If you still do not understand what is going on at that point, then do some research about the error (more than one mutable borrow) and if you still can't find anything, ask a specific question about what you don't understand about the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **not** inconsistency, it is is a **intended behavior** instead.
In first case, no mutable reference is being used. Effectively no issue, so rust compiler is happy.

In second case the rust compiler sees that mutable reference `last` is being dereferenced so it is taken as value access. And as we know rust doesn't allow the two mutable borrows.

Reference: [Deref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html)

To prove my point have tweaked your program a bit

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 0;
    let mut y = &mut x;
    let mut z = &mut y;
    let mut last = &mut z;

    let mut alt_y = &mut x;
    let mut alt_z = &mut alt_y;

    // notice the RHS here assigning 
    // mutable reference of i32 literal
    *last = &mut &mut 4;
    //                ^ not related to x anyhow
}
```

And now the error will reveal the reason behind the issue\

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `x` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:7:21
   |
3  |     let mut y = &mut x;
   |                 ------ first mutable borrow occurs here
...
7  |     let mut alt_y = &mut x;
   |                     ^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
11 |     *last = &mut &mut 4;
   |     ------------------- first borrow later used here
```

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Have gone through the recommendation and I totally agree and understand the reason behind it. But in this case I felt this was necessary.